# CorePlot on iOS - Display same graph in multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, core-plot

I'm using CorePlot in an iOS app to draw a scatter graph. To start with I'm displaying the graph in a view with some other components, but I also want to let the user go into a full screen mode to view more of the graph and pan/zoom.

I don't want to redraw the graph when they switch between full-screen and non-full-screen modes as it seems like a waste of time if I can just reuse the view.

What I've got works fine in terms of displaying the graph in non-full screen, then displaying it in full-screen, but when I come out of full screen mode I still want the user to see the graph in the normal view, but the graph view has disappeared.

This is where I initially setup the graph view in the first view (non-full-screen)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"non full screen graph view did load");

    _graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme];
    [_graph applyTheme:theme];
    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView *)self.view;
    hostingView.collapsesLayers = NO; 
    hostingView.hostedGraph     = _graph;
    //add plots etc. to graph - not shown 
}
```

This works just fine and draws my graph. When I go to full screen mode, this presents the full screen view controller:

```
-(void) goToFullScreen{
    NSLog(@"full screen");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [_rootNavController presentViewController:fullScreenVc animated:NO completion:nil];

    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView *)fullScreenVc.graphView;
    hostingView.collapsesLayers = NO;
    hostingView.hostedGraph     = _graph;
    _graph.defaultPlotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
}
```

This also works just fine and the user can pan around the graph.

This is where the problem comes in - I'm dismissing the full-screen view controller, and somehow losing the graph view as well - when I'm back at the original view controller all the other components are displaying but the view where the graph should be is empty.

```
-(void) exitFullScreen{
    NSLog(@"leaving full screen");
    _graph.defaultPlotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;
    [_rootNavController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong so that I'm losing the graph view? I've checked and at the end of `exitFullScreen:` _graph is not null and it still contains all my plots.

Thanks,
Sarah

Answer (score 0):

Move the graph back to the original hosting view (`hostingView.hostedGraph = _graph;`) before you dismiss the full screen controller. As a Core Animation layer, the graph can only live in one layer hierarchy at a time.

Comment: Just tried this and it hasn't made any difference. I've tried before and after I dismiss the fullScreenView, but still getting an empty view. If I then go back into the fullScreenView it shows up again, but sized as tho it's not full screen so there's something odd happening all together.

Comment: Are you setting the `hostedGraph` to `nil` on one controller before moving the graph to the other controller? The old hosting view might be hanging on to something that interferes with displaying the graph in the new view.